# in my result data it shows blank cells which should not be there rather it should go for an next available data i am using the 2016 excle

Tags: database, excel-formula, excel-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMGps.png)

I don't want the blanks rather it should find next available data which satisfies my given condition

i have tried this formula but if the result is blank it carry as blank

=IF(EXACT("filed",'Master data'!F4),"",'Master data'!A4)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean `=FILTER('Master data'!A4:A500,'Master data'!F4:F500="filed")`?